# Why is this not NAA?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Why has my flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730884/change-tmpdir-in-a-parallel-processing/31749136#31749136) been declined?

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

The answer is two lines, the first one is a suggestion, the second line a citation from the question. 
At least one other user is of my opinion (see their comment below the answer).

Is there something I missed? How is this an answer?

Comment: Well it at least _looks_ like an answer.  By itself, it really looks like a (perhaps downvotable) answer.  I didn't actually notice that it was just copying from the question's error message until you pointed it out.  And since NAA flags don't let you explain why, I'm guessing the mod who handled it didn't notice that either.

Comment: I think the mod who reviewed the flag (or any mod actually) will tell you that although this is a bad answer, it is still an attempt at an answer, and is not damaging enough to require moderator attention.  They'll probably say that if it's not useful, downvote and move on.

Comment: What action do you want a moderator to take? I assume you want them to either delete the answer or convert it to a comment. The problem with either one of these is that a potential answer is lurking in the comments to that post. Let's not throw the baby out with the bath water.

Comment: Why on Earth did she not explain that she at least *tried* to follow up on the recommendation in the error message?  Well, she probably didn't.  So the answer is not inappropriate.

Comment: "Have you tried XYZ" ~= "I think you should try XYZ".  Just because it's in the form of a question doesn't mean it is a question.  As for the second line being a citation, that wasn't clear to me looking at it.  You sure it doesn't contain the answer that the answerer believes the OP should try?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Actually, yes. The answer *is* better suited for a comment. Especially since it is coming from an established user. I don't even see how this could be a potential answer! Don't get me wrong, but in my eyes this is just *Did you read the error message?*...

Comment: I've declined it because it doesn't fit the criteria for the Not An Answer flag. If you feel it is not a helpful answer, just vote accordingly.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt *Which has an answer*.  The fact that an answer to the question was in the error message quoted by the OP doesn't make that answer not an answer.  If it doesn't work, it would make it a bad answer.  The fact that the question doesn't address it at all certainly makes the question a bad question, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Mhm, I hear what you say, but I'm not convinced... To me this is either a request for more information, or a hint to (re-)consider the error message. I have read the the answer marked as a duplicate the first option is actually amongst the "valid reasons".